# Python 2.7 WindowsError exception(123) for unicode characters in path for os.path.getsize call

Tags: python, python-2.7, windowserror

My code is

```
  file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
```

I get the following exception when Unicode characters present in the file_path

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'E:\\Backup\\MyFolder\\~$??????.docx'
```

NOTE: I don't get the same error when I run the same code via Python 3.

My question is how to fix the code to run on both Python 2 and 3?

Comment: Where is `file_path` defined?

Comment: Use the command 2to3

Comment: @JoelCornett file_path could be any folder e.g. C:\MyData

Comment: @GayanPathirage for reproduction purposes, what is an example value for `file_path` that triggers the exception?

Comment: Is `file_path` of type `unicode` or `str`?